# Perl DBIC for nested queries in a dynamically created set of conditions

Tags: mysql, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

**INTRO**

I'm working on a complex form to perform customized queries to a rather large database. Because the user can use one or more fields to search for, I decided to make the conditions dynamic, like:

```
my $where{};


if($some_param && some_param ne ''){
  push @{ $attr->{join} }, { 'aref' => { 'a_deeper_ref' => 'a_much_deeper_ref' }};
  $where->{a_much_deeper_ref.field} = [-and => $some_param, {'!=', undef}];
}

if($another_param && $another_param ne '') {
... # same thing: do the join > build the condition.
}

my $rs = $model->search ($where, $attr);
```

There are about 40-50 fields and while I can address most of them like I did above, a few fields are a bit more tricky ...

**THE ISSUE **

I'll use THE problematic example to make it clearer. Supose yuo have a `laboratory_exams` table, which rows state that a given subject/patient [foreign key to a `subject` table] has been tested for a given clinical exam [foreign key to a `clinical_exam` table] and stores the result for that test.

Now, when the user wants to know which subjects have been tested for, say, both HIV and Hepatitis C, and had a negative result for HIV test and a positive result for Hepatitis C; the form submission would create an array with `exam_ids` and `results` which I can easily retrieve in my controller like

```
my $params = $c->req->parameters;
my @labexams = ref $params->{exam_ids} ? @{$params->{exam_ids}} : $params->{exam_ids};
my @results = ref $params->{results} ? @{$params->{results}} : $params->{results};
```

Of course, when I try to save the condition in the `$where` hash looping the arrays, it overrides the previous one and I end up only with the last element in the array, because...

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#labexams){
 $where->{'labexams.exam_id'} = $labexams[$i];
 $where->{'labexams.result'} = $results[$i];
}
```

... and I just keep writing my condition on either 'labexams.exam_id' or 'labexams.result', which are static.

Notice that I need the resulting SQL to be like

```
... WHERE (labexams.exam_id = $labexam[$i] AND labexams.result = $result[$i]) AND ... #repeat for every exam/result pair
```

**THE ACTUAL QUESTION**

HOW ON EARTH CAN I ACHIEVE THIS?

Comment: Your `$where{}` is wrong. It should be `$where = {}`. But that's not the problem.

Comment: That's not possible. In one row the `labexams.exam_id` can never be 1 and 2 at the same time. There is only one of each column per row. Your SQL would not return data. Build it by hand and run it against the DB, and you'll see no results. `use SQL::Abstract;
my $where;
foreach my $i ( 0 .. 3 ) {
    push @{ $where->{'-and'} },
        [ '-and', [ 'labexams.exam_id', "labexams[$i]" ], [ 'labexams.result', "results[$i]" ] ];
}
my ($statement, @binds) = SQL::Abstract->new->select('foo', '*', $where);
say $statement;
say join ' ', @binds;` will create `OR` in the queries. `AND` can't be.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. This is the output generated by DBIC_TRACE (or by the 'say' in your code).

`SELECT * FROM laboratory_exams WHERE ( ( ( labexams.exam_id = ? OR labexams.result = ? ) AND ( labexams.exam_id = ? OR labexams.result = ? ) AND ( labexams.exam_id IS NULL OR labexams.result IS NULL ) AND ( labexams.exam_id IS NULL OR labexams.result IS NULL ) ) )17 Normal 3 Reactivo`

This won't be the accurate query, though. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up building a SQL expression for the sub-queries and passing that as a reference to the $where hash. Worked like a charm <3

```
  if ($params->{labexam} && $params->{labexam} ne '' ){
  my @labexams = ref $params->{labexam} ? @{$params->{labexam}} : $params->{labexam};
  my @labexam_res = ref $params->{labexam_result} ? @{$params->{labexam_result}} : $params->{labexam_result};
  my $exp_sql;
  push @{ $attr->{join} }, 'laboratory_exams';

  foreach my $i (0 .. $#labexams){
    if($i == 0) {
      $exp_sql .= ' IN ';
    } else {
      $exp_sql .= ' AND laboratory_exams.subject_id IN ';
    }
    $exp_sql .= '(SELECT subject_id FROM laboratory_exams WHERE exam_id = "'.$labexams[$i].'" AND value = "'.$labexam_res[$i].'")';
    $i++;
  }
  $where->{'laboratory_exams.subject_id'} = \$exp_sql;
}
```

Comment: This should be possible with DBIC and maybe easier using DBIx::Class::Helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ResultSet search chaining feature instead of constructing the complex where parameter yourself.

my $rs = ResultSet('Foo')->search(...);
$rs = $rs->search(...);

Comment: Since I'm creating the conditions dynamically, I wouldn't be able to perform a subsearch like this.

Comment: Sure. You can do the calling in the loop. Just overwrite the resultset object.